# Greybox: Can't move focus to the control because it is invisible, not enabled, or of a type that does not accept the focus

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: Visibility error in Internet Explorer when setting focus on an input element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474660/javascript-visibility-error-in-internet-explorer-when-setting-focus-on-an-input)

I have a page that loads within a greybox. I set the focus with `document.getElementById("textfield").focus()` - this works fine when calling the page directly.

But when loaded in a greybox, setting the focus on the onload() event returns:

> Can't move focus to the control because it is invisible, not enabled,
>   or of a type that does not accept the focus

Calling it later works fine.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

It's a well known issue on IE.

You can read about it [here](http://www.mkyong.com/javascript/focus-is-not-working-in-ie-solution/).

The solution is to use the [setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) function to delay the focus() execute time.

you need to replace your line:

```
document.getElementById("textfield").focus();
```

with the following:

```
setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById("textfield").focus(); }, 10);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was annoying the hell out of me, and was causing so many issues with IE8

Comment: I've seen this error only in IE8 and older

Answer (score 1):

Just posting a quick answer to this... had to solve this tonight. Used a setTimeout to call the focus function briefly after the greybox page displays.

A little jQuery used in my version since it was already in this project but you could just as easily use window.onload()

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout ( "document.getElementById('AdminID').focus(); ", 500 ); 
  });
</script>
```