# "Can't move focus to the control because it is invisible" error when clicking on screen control

Tags: javascript, gwt, internet-explorer-7

I am maintaining an (overly complicated) GWT project, and I am encountering a problem with IE7, but not IE8,IE9 IE10 or IE11.

After a certain amount of clicking around the screen, including changing the value in a specific drop down list three times, I start getting the following error, when I click on some (but not all) controls.

`class com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException : (Error) number: -2146826178 description: Can't move focus to the control because it is invisible, not enabled, or of a type that does not accept the focus.: Can't move focus to the control because it is invisible, not enabled, or of a type that does not accept the focus.`

As far as I can tell, the code is not focusing on any controls or doing anything that seems like it. It does not appear to be an issue with the `settimeout()` hack can fix, as the entire screen has loaded, and I am using the mouse to move around

Is there anyway I can find out which control is actually causing this error?

The error only occurs with IE7 in production mode, not development mode. I am trying to get super development mode working, but I have not yet managed it.

Comment: Hi Simon, did you find the solution for this issue? I faced with the same, but in IE8.

Comment: As far as I am aware, the issue only occurs in IE7, and was fixed for IE8

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be related to [JavaScript: Visibility error in Internet Explorer when setting focus on an input element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474660/javascript-visibility-error-in-internet-explorer-when-setting-focus-on-an-input).

As we only have one customer using IE7, the precise timing of the error was almost impossible to find and there appeared to be no other effects, I opted to simply ignore the exception, and pretend it never happened.